# get inner xml from xml node in chrome using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, xml, google-chrome

I need to get inner xml from xml node
I have this code working perfectly in IE but with chrome I cant get the inner xml

```
var result_xml = UXmlHelper.text2xml(result.d); // create xml document
    var xmlStr = $(result_xml).text();//i need to get the inner xml but in chrome it   //return the text.
```

in IE return :`<NewDataSet>
      <Screens>
        <TName>Screens</TName>
        <AppId>1</AppId>
        <AppName>MyStore_1</AppName>
        <AppType>4</AppType>
        <ScreenName>ScrHome</ScreenName>
        <ScrId>9</ScrId>
        <ScrPosition>1</ScrPosition>
        <TemplateId>1</TemplateId>
        <Xml>
          <Screen id="ScrHome" position="1" type="Scr">
            <Properties>
              <Id>ScrHome</Id>
              <Name>Home</Name>
            </Properties>
            <Style />
        ......`

in Chrome return :

```
Screens1MyStore_14ScrHome911ScrHomeHomeCont_MainContainerurl(../Images/iphone-4_RealSize-2.JPG)no-repeat#DCE6F7265507Cont_InnerMainContainer8365Yellow338relativeImgScrollUpImgScrollUp../icons/UpArrow-3-Small.PNG1515scrollStartUpPhScrContImgScrollUpscrollEndImgScrollUpabsolute-7402PhScrContrtltruexxxjustTestrtl#DCE6F7hidden9986relative13ArialrtlImgScrollDownImgScroll....
```

**that what i have :**

```
var result_xml = UXmlHelper.text2xml(result.d); $(result_xml).find('NewDataSet').find("Screens").each(function () { 
var parentScrNode = $(this).find("Xml"); 
});
```

**in the Watch Expressions :**

```
    parentScrNode:
 e.fn.e.init[1] 0: Element 
context: Element 
length: 1 
prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1] 
selector: "Xml" proto: Object[0] –
```

**watch 1:** 
$(parentScrNode).html(): [Exception: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined] **Watch 2 :**

```
parentScrNode.html(): [Exception: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined] **Watch 3 :**
```

parentScrNode.text(): "ScrHomeHomeCont_MainContainerurl(../Images/iphone-4_RealSize-2.JPG)......

any idea??

Thanks alot.

Comment: FYI: Please be sure to follow the guidelines in (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Marking answers to your questions as correct (appropriately of course) will encourage other members to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you should be able to treat XML just like HTML. This way you can directly query for what you want.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/enqBg/

JS

```
alert($('<NewDataSet>  <Screens>    <TName>Screens</TName>    <AppId>1</AppId>    <AppName>MyStore_1</AppName>    <AppType>4</AppType>    <ScreenName>ScrHome</ScreenName>    <ScrId>9</ScrId>    <ScrPosition>1</ScrPosition>    <TemplateId>1</TemplateId>    <Xml>      <Screen id="ScrHome" position="1" type="Scr">        <Properties>          <Id>ScrHome</Id>          <Name>Home</Name>        </Properties>  </Screen>  </Xml>  </Screens>  </NewDataSet>').find('Screens').html());
```

**EDIT 1**

If you want the direct child contents of NewDataSet you'll have to wrap the whole thing in another parent element otherwise jQuery returns `null`. Something like `var YourWrappedXML = '<top><NewDataSet>...</NewDataSet></top>'`. Then you can call `$(YourWrappedXML).find('NewDataSet').html()` to get the contents of `NewDataSet`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/enqBg/1/

**EDIT 2**

Here's an example where your XML is appended to the page.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/enqBg/2/

**EDIT 3**

In the example I had given you I had wrapped `<NewDataSet>...</NewDataSet>` with `<top></top>` resulting in `'<top><NewDataSet>...</NewDataSet></top>'`. By wrapping it we can now search for NewDataSet in our find method. Otherwise NewDataSet is the first element.

If you don't wrap it then you you'll have to use `$(result_xml).find('Screens')` since `$(result_xml)` is `<NewDataSet>`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/enqBg/3/

Also I'm not sure if `result_xml` is string or an object. As far as I know, this will only work with strings (though I could be wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.but I stil cant see the text as xml

Comment: @the_farmer - .text() will strip out any nodes (anything that looks like <Node></Node>) and only display the left over text. You need to use .html() if you want the xml nodes to show up along with the plain text. Also if you append it to the page, you probably won't be able to see it unless you view source since your browser will treat your xml nodes like html nodes and won't be able to render them.

Comment: when I call the .html() i getting error: "[Exception: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined]".I update the upper section so you can see what i have try and what i get in the watch section .Thanks.